# java call python in virtualenv

Tags: java, python

how to use java to call python in virtualenv?
this is my .sh file

```
#!/bin/bash

source activate pytorch41&&
cd /home/cery/workspace/pytorch-CycleGAN-and-pix2pix&&
python test.py --dataroot datasets/vangogh2photo/SHU --name style_vangogh_pretrained --model test --no_dropout
```

when i use it in terminal,it runs but failed in java

```
String[] args = new String[] {"bash","/home/cery/workspace/pytorch-CycleGAN-and-pix2pix/photo.sh"};
        Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(args);
```

how can java change the environment of conda? like use source activate xxx???

Comment: you'd need to say what output you're getting / what in the script is failing and why...  at a guess that `source activate pytorch41` line looks a little weird, are you sure this is being run from the right directory?

Answer (score 0):

i solve this question by set python to /home/cery/anaconda3/bin/python. i guess this is caused by the environment conflict with conda and system